# Server side application for embedded devices

Tags: html, tcp, embedded, websocket, firewall

I'd like some advice as to the best server-side code that can handle real time data from devices and make decisions based on inputs.  A simple example:  Suppose I have a web-enabled thermometer, running a light TCP/IP client stack.  When the temperature gets to 30 degrees, I want the device to contact the server, and then I want the server to send me an email.  I also want the server to be able to send a command to turn on a heater.

The issue at hand here is the ability to start a TCP message from the server, and get through an assortment of arbitrary firewalls and routers, all the way down to the client device.  I know that there are 'workarounds' like polling the server for updates, or 'long polling' where I call up to the server, and keep a connection open in case it has something to send.  The problem here is bandwidth.  Messages are rare, but important, so the headers and handshaking make up 98% of the traffic.

I've been reading up on WebSockets, and it seems like they are exactly what I need, especially when paired with HTML5.

Does anyone know of a ready-to-go server software package that could run on a cloud server, and push data down to my devices using some standardized methods?  I really don't want to reinvent the wheel here, and I can't believe I'm the first to try this.  I see a few folks doing it with their own proprietary solutions, but I'm more interested in buying a one-stop package.

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket is a valid choice for connecting embedded devices to backend infrastructure due to it's low overhead, low latency and compatibility with Web and general network infrastructure. There is a broad range of server implementations available, i.e. Jetty, node.js based etc.

As an example, here is a demo connecting an Arduino device to a WebSocket server and a browser client showing real-time data in a chart:

- https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/wamp/serial2ws
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va7j86thW5M

The technology used there, AutobahnPython, is a Python/Twisted based WebSocket implementation that

- provides server and client implementation
- directly runs on embedded devices like RasperryPi
- makes it easy to access sensors connected via serial or CANbus (since Twisted supports that very well)
- provides RPC and PubSub messsaging patterns on top of WebSocket

The tech is open-source, so you can roll your own solution. If you look for help/services to get it done for you, contact me;) We also provide Tavendo WebMQ, a virtual appliance (VMware, EC2) which adds features, management UI etc and also includes a REST API to push data to WebSocket clients.

Disclaimer: I am author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: I actually just happened upon Autobahn, and it looks very interesting.  How can I contact you directly?

Comment: drop me a mail at: tobias "dot" oberstein "at" tavendo "dot" de

Comment: I just emailed at contact @ ...  Will that work?

Comment: Ok - also sent to the address you suggested.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, thanks! Will answer soon.